# Android App is stuck in a loading screen - Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

This is a specific issue I'm having with my app in Android Studio. I'm making a weather app and I need to call the Yahoo weather API. I added a loading screen while the user waits for the app to connect to internet but it just stays at that loading. Does the Yahoo weather service not work anymore?

Here's my main activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements YahooServiceCallback {

private ImageView weatherIcon;
private TextView temperature;
private TextView condition;
private TextView location;

private YahooWeatherService service;
private ProgressDialog dialog;
private int resourceId;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    weatherIcon = findViewById(R.id.weatherIcon);
    temperature = findViewById(R.id.temperature);
    condition = findViewById(R.id.condition);
    location = findViewById(R.id.location);

    service = new YahooWeatherService(this);
    dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    dialog.setMessage("Loading...");
    dialog.show();

    service.refreshWeather("Manalapan, NJ", resourceId);

}

@Override
public void serviceSuccess(Channel channel, int resourceId) {
    dialog.hide();

    item item = channel.getItem();
    int resource = getResources().getIdentifier("drawable/icon_"+ item.getCondition().getCode(), null, getPackageName());

    @SuppressLint({"NewApi", "LocalSuppress"})
    Drawable weatherIconDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(resourceId, null);

    weatherIcon.setImageDrawable(weatherIconDrawable);

    temperature.setText(item.getCondition().getTemperature()+"\u00B0"+channel.getUnits().getTemperature());
    condition.setText(item.getCondition().getDescription());
    location.setText(service.getLocation());
}

@Override
public void serviceFailure(Exception exception) {
    Toast.makeText(this, exception.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
}
```

and my **YahooWeatherService.java** class

```
public class YahooWeatherService {
private YahooServiceCallback callback;
private String location;
private Exception error;

public YahooWeatherService(YahooServiceCallback callback) {
    this.callback = callback;
}

public String getLocation() {
    return location;
}

@SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
public void refreshWeather(final String location, final int resourceId) {
    this.location = location;
    new AsyncTask<String, Void, String>() {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {

            String YQL = String.format("select * from weather.forecast where woeid in (select woeid from geo.places(1) where text=\"%s\")", strings[0]);

            String endpoint = String.format("https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=%s&format=json", Uri.encode(YQL));

            try {
                URL url = new URL(endpoint);

                URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
                InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();

                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    result.append(line);
                }

                return result.toString();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                error = e;
                return null;
            }
        }
    };
}
}
```

Comment: Did u debug it? Put a breakpoint inside the asynctask and check what you got.

Comment: Where is your `onPostExecute` method of `AsyncTask`

Comment: @AbuYousuf, very good point. It does not even have onPostExecute, or at least it does not look like. As I said debug it and check what happens. I would suggest read a bit about AsyncTask(although not sure who uses it anymore) and then start adding it to your project.

Answer (score 0):

I Founded the error this is a logical error as you have used dialog.show(); method but when you receives the values from Yahoo weather api you need to call dialog.dismiss(); method to dismiss the the progress dialog so that the loading can be dismissed and results can be showed to the user

Comment: So where should I add the dialog.dismiss(); statement?

Answer (score 0):

As I can see you are not calling execute on the AsyncTask. You are not even getting to the point of loading data. Add:

```
.yourAsyncTask.execute(location)
```

Example:

```
@SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
public void refreshWeather(final String location) {
    this.location = location;
    new AsyncTask<String, Void, String>() {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {

            String YQL = String.format("select * from weather.forecast where woeid in (select woeid from geo.places(1) where text=\"%s\")", strings[0]);

            String endpoint = String.format("https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=%s&format=json", Uri.encode(YQL));

            try {
                URL url = new URL(endpoint);

                URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
                InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();

                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    result.append(line);
                }

                return result.toString();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                error = e;
                return null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            //param1 and param2 are the ones from the callback.
            callback.serviceSuccess(param1, param2);
        }
    }.execute(location);
}
```

It should return you the String data you want.

**Edit** 
Full solution

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements YahooWeatherCallback {

    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private TextView temperature;
    private TextView condition;
    private TextView location;

    private ProgressDialog dialog;

    private YahooWeatherService service;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // weatherIcon = findViewById(R.id.weatherIcon);
        temperature = findViewById(R.id.tv_condition_show);
        condition = findViewById(R.id.tv_condition_show);
        location = findViewById(R.id.tv_location_show);

        service = new YahooWeatherService(this);
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        dialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        dialog.show();

        service.refreshWeather("Manalapan, NJ");

    }


    @Override
    public void serviceFailure(Exception exception) {

    }


    @Override
    public void serviceSuccess(Channel channel) {
        Log.d(TAG, "result:" + channel.getTitle());
        dialog.hide();
    }
}

//callback
 public interface YahooWeatherCallback {
    void serviceSuccess(Channel channel);

    void serviceFailure(Exception exception);
 }


 //service
  public class YahooWeatherService {


    private YahooWeatherCallback callback;
    private String location;
    private Exception error;

     public String getLocation() {
        return location;
     }

     public YahooWeatherService(YahooWeatherCallback callback) {
        this.callback = callback;
     }

     @SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
     public void refreshWeather(final String location) {
         this.location = location;
         new AsyncTask<String, Void, String>() {
             @Override
             protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {

                 String YQL = String.format("select * from weather.forecast where woeid in (select woeid from geo.places(1) where text=\"%s\")", strings[0]);

                 String endpoint = String.format("https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=%s&format=json", Uri.encode(YQL));

                 try {
                     URL url = new URL(endpoint);

                     URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
                     InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();

                      BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                      StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
                      String line;
                      while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                         result.append(line);
                      }

                      return result.toString();

                  } catch (Exception e) {
                      error = e;
                      return null;
                  }
              }

              @Override
              protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
                  callback.serviceSuccess(new Channel());
              }
          }.execute(location);
      }
  }

    //Channel
    public class Channel {
       //here you can add more data.
    }
```

As you can see I stripped some data just for you to have a start.

Comment: Where should I add this statement?

Comment: Unfortunately, no it didn't work. I still am stuck on the loading screen.

Comment: I tested it with a simple scenario, it worked pretty fine. You probably don't get passed the onPostExecute. Put logs in the success(serviceSuccess method) part and see if you get there. Next put logs in the onPostExecute and see if you get there. Next put logs in the doInBackground and see how far you got.